# mongodb for ecommece shop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, e-commerce

With a series of Google searches, I came across a series of objections about MongoDB for the online store
For example

https://hashnode.com/post/mongodb-vs-mysql-for-ecommerce-cip3y6265044zya535mhe565v

And now I have a project that is an online store with nodejs and mongoose
In your opinion, according to update 4 that acid and multi doc is supported, is there a problem for such a project (because I am almost finish it :()

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-multi-document-acid-transactions-general-availability

This Store has about 5,000 products and 1500 visitors per a day now use WooCommerce!

Answer (score 1):

mongodb support multi-document transactions in version>=4.2 , so there is no issue to work with transactions, but the biggest advantage to use mongo is that you will provide easy  scalable and highly-available cloud native backend to your project , also you will have the advantage to change the schema any time in the future and since there is no predefined schema you will not loose time to define initially complex relations between tables , moreover after the online store grows you can very easy distribute and replicate to multiple geographical locations, not mentioning that all cloud providers support mongo and there is drivers and support in almost all platforms and languages ...

Comment: hi i know the advantage of mongodb because i red sth about acid that nosql doesn't not support and because we have a lots of update we are afraid of confilits and mistakes

Comment: mongodb in all versions support ACID at document level   and having the possibility to add up to 100 nested objects inside single document  make it perfectly suitable for ecommerce shop apps   , some old helpfull article here  ( the time it was written multi-document transactions where not available ) : https://medium.com/@ali.atwa/mongodb-and-e-commerce-ce7a6ca79bcb    and another interesting here: https://www.infoq.com/articles/data-model-mongodb/